# Multiple microservices in scheduled mode

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, microservices

We have many spring boot based microservices running. Most of them are scheduled and need to run on a daily once or weekly once pattern. We are deploying each microservice in a separate docker container. We are not using any container orchestration technology like kubernetes.

Since the process is up always, it won't release memory even if it is doing nothing. This actually creates an issue for other microservices running in the same host.

Is there any way we can make these microservices or containers run as per schedule and release the resources once done? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply start the container on a schedule using [cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) (assuming Unix-like systems) or equivalents like Windows Scheduler.

Then have the job process simply exit after when the job is complete. (Exiting the main process will stop the container).  `cron` will then re-start the container again at the next scheduled time.

More cron tutorials:

- https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800
- https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/

Comment: How will we know if the job has completed? Each time, the batch process may take variable amount of time depending on how much data to process.

Comment: The batch job itself knows when it's done, right?   Just have the job exit() whenever it's done, stopping the JVM and the container.  This doesn't need to be coordinated from outside the container.

Comment: Thanks very much peekay. I didn't think of that. Will check it out

Comment: @SRaj This [thread on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/7nb6c8/crontab_to_run_a_docker_job/) might give some further inspiration.